# When Reinstalling Grub i am getting this error

Tags: kali-linux

When I typed This Command To Repair Grub:

```
$ sudo mount /dev/sda7 /mnt
$ mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
$ mount --bind /dev/pts /mnt /dev/pts
$ mount --bind  /proc /mnt/proc
$ mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys
$ chroot /mnt
$ grub-install /dev/sda
Installing for x86_64-efi platform
grub-install: error: cannot find EFI directory.
```

I Am Getting This Error.

Comment: @user4838962 i am new to linux can u explain a bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run `lsblk` and `sudo blkid` commands to see a list of drives and their partitions. See which partition is your `EFI boot` partition, I'm not quite sure about the official name, but it should be something like `EFI boot`. Let's assume the `EFI boot` partition is `/dev/sda1`. Now run the following command before doing `chroot`:

```
$ sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/boot/efi
```

Then do the `chroot`:

```
$ sudo chroot /mnt
```